# RecyclerView no actualiza EditText, ni Checkbox

Tags: android, recyclerview, checkbox, edittext

Hola comunidad StackOverflow tengo un problema tengo una lista de 30 elementos inicialmente el primer elemento tiene 4.4 en la segunda columna lo cambio a 4.9 scroleo hacia abajo y no se guarda el valor regresa a 4.4. Hago lo mismo con el segundo elemento de 2.4 lo cambio a 2.5 lo pueden ver en el gif hagan click al gif para ver el problema. Lo que quiero es que se guarde el valor cuando scroleas y no regrese al inicial.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta el código fuente https://github.com/Miguel546/recyclerviewEtCb

Este es el código para poder llenar el RecyclerView.

```
OrdenTempAdapter ordenTempAdapter = new OrdenTempAdapter(getApplicationContext());
ordenTempAdapter.setPalletTempModelList(palletTempModelList);
rvLsPallet.setHasFixedSize(true);
rvLsPallet.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
rvLsPallet.setAdapter(ordenTempAdapter);
```

Y los elementos los lleno con el siguiente metodo setPalletTemp

```
void setPalletTemp(PalletTempModel palletTemp) {
            tvPallet.setText(palletTemp.getNumePallet());
            tvTemperatura.setText(palletTemp.getTemperatura());
            checkboxCamara.setChecked(palletTemp.rutaPallet == 1 ? true: false);
}
```

El mismo problema del EditText es para el checkbox cuando haces un cambio lo scroleas y no se guarda el cambio. Lo que se quiere es que cuando cambies algún valor de la lista y scrolees el cambio se guarde no que vuelva al valor inicial.

Por favor ayúdenme.

Saludos.

Luis Miguel Casas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo solucioné con las siguientes líneas de código en el Adapter.

```
checkboxCamara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    palletTempModelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).rutaPallet = (checkboxCamara.isChecked() == true ? 1: 0);
                }
            });
tvTemperatura.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                    palletTempModelList.get(getAdapterPosition()).temperatura = s.toString();
                }

                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                }
            });
```

Era un TextWatcher para el EditText y un onClickListener para el checkbox.

El codigo solucionado esta aquí --> https://github.com/Miguel546/recyclerviewEtCb